# Running latex through perl batch file

Tags: perl, exceltex

I am interested in running multiple latex files in a directory from perl.  I will have as many as 100 .tex files to run at once, and I was wondering if someone could suggest a perl script or package that I could modify to do this quickly.

I am planning on generating the .tex files using exceltex (since it is a large database of questions), and then executing the perl script on the folder to generate the .pdf files.

Any advice would be appreciated.

Comment: This shouldn't be too hard to do.  But the exact method will depend on your directory/file structures.  For example, will perl be called on all the files in some base directory?  If not, is it possible to build a database of files you want to process through LaTeX?

Comment: I think this is off-topic: while I see you got what looks like a good answer, it's not at all about TeX or something that TeX expertise helps with.

Comment: Hi Joseph: I guess I see what you mean, but I posted it here in case there was a .tex package that might help me do this.  I didn't even know that exceltex existed before this forum.  So, I'm sorry if this appeared to be an off-topic post.

Answer (score 2):

If you're going to process all files in a directory, you can do something along the lines of

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use strict 'vars';
my @files = <*.tex>;
foreach my $file ( @files )
  {
    system("pdflatex $file");
  }
```

Or if you have some file, call it `tobe_compiled.txt`, which lists names of file:

```
file_01.tex
file_02.tex
file_03.tex
```

Then you could write a perl script as

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
open FILE, "<tobe_compiled.txt";
my @files = <FILE>;
close FILE;
foreach my $file ( @files )
  {
    system("pdflatex $file");
  }
```