# Compile all tex files within a folder at once

Tags: pdftex, luatex, compiling, linux

Is there a way to compile all tex files within a specific folder, from LINUX terminal, at once?

I would like to do this using `pdflatex` or `lualatex` in a way to create a pdf file for each distinc original tex file.

This question is not about creating individual tex files to form a single pdf file using `\input` or `\include`, at all.

Comment: `cd myfolder; for i in *.tex; do pdflatex $i;done` ?

Comment: here: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/127243/running-latex-through-perl-batch-file you'll find a perl script that might solve your problem,

Comment: I often use the Makefile available here: https://code.google.com/p/latex-makefile/

Comment: @DavidCarlisle it seems that you solved my problem. My question clearly displays my lack of knowledge on Linux.

Answer (score 29, accepted):

You could use a loop in the shell eg

```
cd myfolder; for i in *.tex; do pdflatex $i;done
```

Comment: `latexmk -pdf "$i"` seems more productive and sure than `pdflatex $i`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit yes or just `make` with a suitable makefile, but I wanted to avoid bringing in other commands and provide simplest answer to the question that I could think of (and it's also something I do myself quite a lot, not necessarily for tex but in general)

Comment: Ok. But `"$i"` seems more sure than `$i`...

Comment: @PaulGaborit why? I never quote the shell variable in that context (only matters if you have spaces in filenames and they are evil anyway:-)

Comment: Spaces are not the only problem characters. There is also the semicolons, and some other characters ...

Answer (score 17):

By default `latexmk` compiles all tex files in the current directory, including doing the necessary calls to `biber`, `bibtex`, etc.  To run `pdflatex` on the files use

```
latexmk -pdf
```

or for `lualatex`

```
latexmk -lualatex
```

You can set default behaviour via a configuration file.

Comment: I second. This is the way to go, because latexmk will compile a file twice, if necessary e.g. for references etc.

Comment: @AndrewSwann Sorry, I forgot to comment on this answer. It looks nice and clean. But, I couldn't run `latexmk -lualatex` on my Linux. The reason is that I already had problems to make lualatex work, in the first place. I just don't like the idea of having to care about the settings of a fourth element (latexmk), in addition to pdflatex, bibtex and lualatex.

Comment: If `lualatex` won't run on your system, then nothing that calls `lualatex`, including `latexmk -lualatex`, stands a chance of working.  If you are just interested in running `pdflatex` then `latexmk -pdf` will do that for you, and will not call `lualatex`.

Answer (score 5):

I imagine there are quite a few ways to do this- David Carlisle mentioned one in his comment, here's another:

```
find -name "*.tex"|while read file; do pdflatex "$file";done
```

Comment: Be careful where you call that!  If I did that in my home directory, that'd be about 2100 `.tex` files...

Comment: Another variant: `find -name "*.tex" -exec pdflatex '{}' \;`

Comment: @jon *Be careful where you call that*... that's true for most commands :)

Comment: To surpass the levels, just do: `find -maxdepth 1 -name "*.tex" -exec pdflatex '{}' \;`

Comment: @zeroth -- Right.  I was trying to suggest that some comment about `find`'s recursivity should be made, not that I just accidentally tried to latex 2100 files.