# How to compile all LaTeX files in subdirectories?

Tags: pdftex, compiling

I have a directory which has subdirectories (of arbitrary depth) that all have files, but have LaTeX (.tex) files as well. However, I do not want to go to each file and compile each separately. Is there a script to compile all of them at once from the top directory?

Comment: Which operating system are you using?

Comment: Mac OS X Mavericks.

Comment: Welcome to the site! have you seen [Compile all tex files within a folder at once](http://tex.stackexchange.com/q/169176)