# Compile all latex documents in subdirectories (when documents involve multiple files)

Tags: compiling, mac, linux, latexmk

I have a directory containing many separate latex documents, either directly or inside subdirectories; and I want to compile all these documents simultaneously.  Some of these documents involve multiple `.tex` files — a master file that includes some other file(s).

The following questions ask something very similar:

- [Compile all tex files within a folder at once](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169176/)
- [How to compile all LaTeX files in subdirectories?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/175944/)

However, the answers given there don’t work in my situation; they essentially tell `latexmk` (or `pdflatex`, or whatever) to attempt to compile *all `.tex` files* within the current directory.  That works when each `.tex` file is an individual document, but fails when there are multiple-file documents, for two reasons:

- the `.tex` files that are intended just as includes don’t compile individually, so `latexmk` chokes on these
- even when compiling the master file of a document, `latexmk` may fail because it tries to locate the requested include files within the current directory, not within the directory where the master file lives.

**Does anyone have a good command-line one liner to compile all documents, in this situation?**

The closest I’ve come is `ag -lR --null 'documentclass' . | xargs -0 latexmk`  This runs `latexmk` on all files containing `documentclass`, which solves the first issue above by picking out the master files (at least to a first approximation); but it doesn’t solve the second issue, of finding the correct include files.

(I am on Mac OS; but I guess answers should be similar for all system with a unix-/linux-like command-line.)

Comment: Try passing the `-cd` argument to `latexmk`. This will cause `latexmk` to change to the directory of your `tex` file and so should then find the included files.

Comment: @DavidPurton: Thankyou! That, added to the attempt I mention, solves the problem.  If you make it an answer, I’ll accept it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can pass the `-cd` argument to `latexmk`. This will cause `latexmk` to change to the directory of your `tex` file and so should then find the included files.

Comment: Great, that works perfectly — thanks!  So just for easy reference/copy-pasting: the resulting full command is `grep -lR --null 'documentclass' . | xargs -0 latexmk -cd` (or with `ag` instead of `grep`, to ignore files in `.gitignore`, and a few other subtle differences).