# can `latexmk` process multiple files in parallel?

Tags: luatex, latexmk

To compile a number of `*.tex` files in several subdirectories I use

```
find -name *.tex -exec latexmk -lualatex  {} \;
```

as per [recommendation here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/169176/compile-all-tex-files-within-a-folder-at-once).

Works fine, but uses only one core. What must be changed to process in parallel?

Comment: you can run each latexmk in the background see https://stackoverflow.com/a/20146763

Comment: I tried `find -name *.tex -exec 'latexmk -lualatex  {} &' \;` but it fails with `no such file`. What is the trick?

Comment: as shown there you need to exec a shell eg `sh` that then calls latexmk so that `&` is seen by the shell and backgrounds the process. You can't use `&` if you directly exec latexmk.  simpler is `for i in *.tex */*.tex; do latexmk "$i" & done`  so long as your directory structure not too deep

Comment: Thank you. The command works when given on the command line but if I call it within a program it does nothing (even if I wait for completion for the call). Why no pdf produced?

Comment: presumably your calling convention is wrong but it will depend on the program and operating system and your default shell and isn't really tex related, sorry I don't think I can guess any more suggestions.

Answer (score 1):

With the help of @David Carlisle, I found two solutions which work on the command line:

```
for i in *.tex */*.tex */*/*.tex */*/*/*.tex; do latexmk "$i" & done
```

or, using `find` and a second bash file:

```
find . -name *.tex -exec sh mk.sh {} \;
```

where mk.sh is

```
#!/bin/bash
latexmk "$1" &
```

In my example case, the parallelism on an eight core cpu achieved a factor 2 reduction of processing time. I was not able to use these solutions when included in a program.

I think it would be attractive, if  `latexmk` would offer an option to convert all `.tex` files in subtree in parallel.

Comment: What do you mean with 'a program'. That's very unspecific. Is the program you've in mind in any way related to TeX?

Comment: @lukeflo I suspect it refers to an editor, but I'm not sure.

Comment: Can you edit your question so it is clearer? That will make this easier for other users to find if they want to do the same thing.

Comment: @cfr that's likely. Maybe the script to be run as recipe in vscode or something similar. We are looking forward for some clarification :)

Comment: @lukeflo Indeed ;)

Comment: Sorry for not being specific: the program is written in Haskell running on a linux-debian OS. It uses a call `createProcess` (https://hackage.haskell.org/package/process-1.6.18.0/docs/System-Process.html#v:createProcess_) to call one of the two shell commands I found working (without waiting for completion). I suspect that the issue is one of the interaction between the `latexmk` perl scrip, the shell and the way Haskell calls it, which together is beyond my experience. Given that it only halfs the processing time, I gave up.  Thank you for your interest!

Comment: I compile haskell code to an executablel programs to produce the latex files and then execute them. I would like to have a way to include the faster running versions in this program. unfortunately, I can only get it to work as bash commands and not inside the program.